# SecretManagerServiceClient raises 403 Permission denied CONSUMER_INVALID in Google App Engine but `gcloud secrets versions access` works

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

### Background:

- I'm trying to deploy a Django app to the Google App Engine (GAE) standard environment in the python39 runtime
- The database configuration is stored in a Secret Manager secret version, similar to Google's GAE Django tutorial ([link](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine))
- The app is run as a user-managed service account `server@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com`, which has the appropriate permissions to access the secret, as can be confirmed using `gcloud secret versions access`

### Problem:

- In the Django `settings.py` module, when I try to access the secret using `google.cloud.secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient.access_secret_version(...)`, I get the following `CONSUMER_INVALID` error:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Permission denied on resource project myproject. [links {
    description: "Google developer console API key"
    url: "https://console.developers.google.com/project/myproject/apiui/credential"
  }
  , reason: "CONSUMER_INVALID"
  domain: "googleapis.com"
  metadata {
    key: "service"
    value: "secretmanager.googleapis.com"
  }
  metadata {
    key: "consumer"
    value: "projects/myproject"
  }
```

### My Debugging

- I *cannot* reproduce the error above *outside* of GAE;

  - I can confirm that the SA can access the secret:

```
gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret=server_env --project myproject \
  --impersonate-service-account=server@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

```
WARNING: This command is using service account impersonation. All API calls will be executed as [server@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com].

DATABASE_URL='postgres://django:...'
SECRET_KEY='...'
```

- I've also confirmed I run the django app locally with service account impersonation and make the above `access_secret_version(...)` calls
- In desperation I even created an API key for the project and hardcoded it into my `settings.py` file, and this *also* raises the same error
- I've confirmed the following settings in the project:

  - the app is running with using the correct user-managed SA
  - the call to `access_secret_version` is being made with the correct SA (ie that the credentials are being pulled from the GAE environment correctly)
  - the project has the `secretmanager.googleapis.com` service enabled, and has billing enabled and the billing account is active

**If you have any suggestions for a configuration or method to help debug this, I'd much appreciate it!**

### Relevant Code Snippets

#### `app.yaml`

```
service_account: server@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com

runtime: python39

handlers:
# This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's static
# directory.
- url: /_static
  static_dir: _static/

# This handler routes all requests not caught above to your main app. It is
# required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted (along with
# the entire handlers section) when there are no static files defined.
- url: /.*
  script: auto

env_variables:
  ...

inbound_services:
  - mail
  - mail_bounce

app_engine_apis: true
```

#### Service Account Creation & Permissions

- The SA is created with Terraform as below
- (The SA doesn't have the role `roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor`, but has an IAM binding directly on the secret itself)

```
resource "google_service_account" "frontend_server" {
  project      = google_project.project.project_id
  account_id   = "server"
  display_name = "Frontend Server Service Account"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "frontend_server" {
  depends_on = [
    google_service_account.frontend_server,
  ]
  for_each = toset([
    "roles/appengine.serviceAgent",
    "roles/cloudsql.client",
    "roles/cloudsql.instanceUser",
    "roles/secretmanager.viewer",
    "roles/storage.objectViewer",
  ])
  project  = google_project.project.project_id
  role     = each.key
  member   = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.frontend_server.email}"
}
```

#### Django `settings.py`

The relevant sections of the app `settings.py` are shown below; the `access_secret_version` raises the

```
import logging
import environ
from google.cloud import secretmanager
import google.auth

# Load secrets from secret manager; the client is auth'd by SA IAM policies
credentials, project = google.auth.default(
  scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
)
secretmanager_client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient(credentials=credentials)

# Load the database connection string into the environment
secrets = [
  f"projects/{GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}/secrets/server_env/versions/latest",
]
for name in secrets:
  try:
    logging.info(f"Reading secret {name} into django settings module...")
    payload = secretmanager_client.access_secret_version(name=name).payload.data.decode("UTF-8")
    env.read_env(io.StringIO(payload))
  except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f"Encountered error when accessing secret {name}: {e}")
    logging.error(f"Client credentials during error: {secretmanager_client._transport._credentials.__dict__}")
    raise e from None
```

Answer (score 1):

Sigh. This was a terrible case of a hard-to-read typo in the app.yaml file. The project had a mnemonic substring with very similar letters that I had mistyped and just couldn't see.

FWIW, if anyone is running into a similar flub, you can at least avoid this one source of error:

- I was passing in a project prefix string and an environment string through the `app.yaml` file, and then `settings.py` file I concatenated these strings to make the project
- When running `gcloud app deploy` the (correct) concatenated project string also existed in my shell `$GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` variable, so the deployment happened correctly with the right project id
- However I removed the concatenation code in `settings.py` in favour of the  `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` env variable that is always present in GAE ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#environment_variables))

TLDR: DRY is good..

Comment: Same happened for me - I was executing a curl command direct to the REST API: `curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" https://secretmanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECTNAME/secrets` , but I had misspelled the project name. The result was that weird error message. Fixing the typo in the project name avoids the error. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You have granted the incorrect role. Have a look to that [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/access-control).

- Secret Viewer role allows you to view the secret and versions but NOT the content.
- Secret Accessor role allows you to access to secret version content.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'm afraid this wasn't the case here, since there are direct `roles/secretmanager.Accessor` IAM bindings for the SA on the secret itself (rather than for all secrets in the project), and I can successfully impersonate the SA and retrieve the secrets the SA permissions